# Unix Shell Scripting - expr syntax issue

Tags: directory, size, expr

I am trying to find total size of a current directory and the shell script is failing at expr command. below is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "This program summarizes the space size of current directory"

sum=0

for filename in *.sh
do
    fsize=`du -b $filename`
    echo "file name is: $filename Size is:$fsize"
    sum=`expr $sum + $fsize`        
done
echo "Total space of the directory is $sum"
```

Comment: when i execute it throws "expr: syntax error".

Comment: You can do the same using just `du -cb *.sh`. What else are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

du returns the size and filename, you just want the total size.
Try changing your fsize assignment

```
fsize=$(du -b $filename | awk '{print $1}')
```

Total size of directory contents, excluding subdirectories and the directory itself:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs du -bS | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

du will give actual space used by a directory, so I had to use "find" to really only match files, and awk to add the sizes.

Comment: Question on your statement "du -b  --summarize -S | awk '{print $1}'"

Comment: Question. Below is the output of ls -l -a:
4096 Jan 26 22:06 .
4096 Jan 26 22:06 ..
  346 Jan 20 01:26 BreakContinue.sh
  805 Jan 17 01:23 DirectorySize.sh
  597 Jan 19 02:22 Example1.sh
1245 Jan 13 01:54 fileprocess.sh
  325 Jan 12 23:31 first1.sh
  477 Jan 14 02:29 LineCount.sh
    27 Jan 20 02:44 Outfile.txt
  446 Jan 16 20:56 PatternMatch.sh
  719 Jan 18 01:54 RetireAge.sh
  409 Jan 21 02:01 SizeSum1.sh
  420 Jan 26 22:06 SizeSum.sh
  142 Jan 13 21:04 sum.sh
[edureka@localhost Scripts]$ du -b --summarize -S
10054 . output should have been "5958". why it is 10054?

Comment: Yeah that is odd; I ran "find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs du -bS | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'" to add up bytes of everything in the current directory, and it came out 12354 bytes smaller than "du -Sb --summarize".  Will see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Guessing a bit here, but my using `du` without specifying files is going to include actual space used by the directory itself, in addition to the files.  I'm updating my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Try `du -b somefile`. It will print size and name like this:

```
263     test.sh
```

Then you are trying to add both size and name arithmetically to `sum` which will never work.

You need to either slice away the file name or, better, use [`stat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat%20%60stat%60) instead of `du`:

```
fsize=`stat -c "%s" $filename`
```

...and for `bash` there is a bit cleaner way to do the math which is described [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html):

```
sum=$(($sum + $fsize))
```

output:

```
This program summarizes the space size of current directory
file name is: t.sh Size is:270
Total space of the directory is 270
```